# Operation returned an invalid status code ‘Forbidden’ at Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Language.LUIS.Runtime

Tags: .net, .net-core, botframework, azure-language-understanding

My bot was working fine, but all of a sudden it started failing with the following error :**Operation returned an invalid status code ‘Forbidden’**

Any idea what's going on. 
few days back I noticed some email notifications stating " **You are approaching the quota limit on you subscription to the LUIS API - Free product. This quota will be renewed on 09/26/2019.** "

Is this error has anything to do with my quota limit on my subscription to the LUIS API ?How can I upgrade ?

```
Operation returned an invalid status code ‘Forbidden’
at Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Language.LUIS.Runtime.Prediction.ResolveWithHttpMessagesAsync(String appId, String query, Nullable1 timezoneOffset, Nullable1 verbose, Nullable1 staging, Nullable1 spellCheck, String bingSpellCheckSubscriptionKey, Nullable1 log, Dictionary2 customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Language.LUIS.Runtime.PredictionExtensions.ResolveAsync(IPrediction operations, String appId, String query, Nullable1 timezoneOffset, Nullable1 verbose, Nullable1 staging, Nullable1 spellCheck, String bingSpellCheckSubscriptionKey, Nullable1 log, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.Luis.LuisRecognizer.RecognizeInternalAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, Dictionary2 telemetryProperties, Dictionary2 telemetryMetrics, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.Luis.LuisRecognizer.RecognizeAsync[T](ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

**Update**

I upgraded my luis app to standard tier. But still I am facing the same error

Comment: Entirely related to your quota limit.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the exception info, your LUIS API service tier is a free one and it has reached quota limitation which caused the [403 forbidden error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-reference-response-codes).For details about LUIS API pricing you can see [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cognitive-services/language-understanding-intelligent-services/) .

[image]

If you want to grade your LUIS API service tier , go to Azure portal and select your LUIS service click "pricing tier" to upgrade it : 
[image]

Comment: I actually upgraded to standard tier, but still I am getting the same error

Answer (score 1):

Just upgrading to standard tier will not resolve this error.

Here is how I got that resolved

```
--> upgraded LUIS app to standard tier
--> regenerated the primary Key, updated in key vault 
--> Go to Luis.AI >>application settings>>Azure resources >>"Add prediction resource" ,

        pricing tier should show as "standard" and the your expected Region
-> publish your luis app
```

After this "unauthorized" error is gone